# SQL Query: if a row contains a specific value, ignore all rows that have the same data identifier

Tags: sqlite

I have this table `process_io_table`:

| process_name | input | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AVA | AVA_IN1 | AVA_RESULT |
| AVA | AVA_IN2 | AVA_RESULT |
| VSC | VSC_IN1 | VSC_RESULT |
| VSC | AVA_RESULT | VSC_RESULT |

I would like to get the distinct list of process_names that do not have a row that has an input value found in the output column. In this example, I would expect to return `process_name` 'AVA' because AVA input rows do not contain a value from the output column. VSC on the other hand would not be included because it has a row with an input found in the output column (`AVA_RESULT`).

I tried something along the lines of

```
SELECT DISTINCT io.process_name
FROM process_io_table io
WHERE io.input NOT IN (SELECT io.output FROM process_io_table io)
```

However, this still returns both AVA and VSC because VSC has a row with an input not in the output table (VSC_IN1).

How do I get process_names that don't have ANY rows with input values found in the output column?

UPDATE: I think with the help of the person who answered I have it figured out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT R.process_name
FROM process_io_table as R
WHERE R.process_name NOT IN( -- Gets process_names NOT IN the list of process_names I don't want
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.process_name
    FROM R t1
    WHERE EXISTS ( -- finds the process_names I DON'T want
        SELECT 1 
        FROM R t2
        WHERE t1.input= t2.output
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.

```
SELECT DISTINCT io.process_name
FROM process_io_table io1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM process_io_table io2
  WHERE io1.input = io2.output
)
```

Comment: If i do SELECT * instead of SELECT DISTINCT io.process_name, I still get this row: VSC|VSC_IN1|VSC_RESULT. In my particular case 'process_io_table' is actual a temporary structure 'R' using a WITH R AS(...) statement, that wouldn't have an effect would it? So when I do the SELECT DISTINCT io.process_name, I am still getting AVA and VSC